# Increasing the number of workers for a parfor loop

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I am using a `parfor` loop and it uses only 4 workers, even when the preferred number of workers is 12. How can I increase the number of workers to at least 8?

Comment: If the answer below helped you, please consider accepting it. That gives both you and me a little of reputation, and signals to the community at large that you no longer need help. There is no obligation to do so however.

Answer (score 2):

```
parpool(12)
parfor
    ...
end
```

Use [`parpool`](http://mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parpool.html) to set the number of workers. Note that you must have a PC with 12 *physical* cores, so an Intel-processor with 4 physical cores won't do 8 workers, even though Intel advertises with "8 cores", since four of them are virtual.